# Pseudo-class :visited not working as expected

Tags: html, css

My code consists of the four basic pseudo-classes of which all work as expected with the exception of the **:visited** psueudo-class. The set color property of this pseudo-class does not work well and the background property is just dead. What can be wrong? I want to believe it has nothing to do with its position relative to other pseudo-classes.

[image: description image]

```css
.navBar-Container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navBar-Container .schoolBatch {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navBar-Container .schoolLogo {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
}

.navBar-Container .schoolTitle {
  margin-left: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navBar-Container .schoolName {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Hemi Head", "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  color: navy;
}

.navBar-Container .schoolMotto {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.navBar-Container ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 0;
}

.navBar-Container ul>li a:link {
  color: navy;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navBar-Container ul>li a:visited {
  color: red;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.navBar-Container ul>li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: navy;
}

.navBar-Container ul>li a:active {
  color: purple;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar-Container">
  <div class="schoolBatch col-4">
    <div class="schoolLogo-Container"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x60" class="schoolLogo" alt="BGS Logo" /></div>
    <div class="schoolTitle">
      <div class="schoolName">BETHEL GEMINI SCHOOLS</div>
      <p class="schoolMotto">Heaven's Light, Our Ground</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navBar col-8">
    <ul class="navBar-Items">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="admissions.html">Admissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="academics.html">Academics</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="downloads.html">Downloads</a></li>
      <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: @Manjuboyz — Why do you say that? The OP didn't say that the problem only occurs while a link is being clicked on.

Comment: @Manjuboyz — I know. `:active` can't override that unless `:active` **applies**, which it doesn't except while the link is being clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the transparency between unvisited and visited links, as you otherwise would be able to using `rgba()`, `hsla()`, or the `transparent` keyword. The default value of background-color is `transparent`. You need to specify a different value, otherwise changes on :visited won't apply. Check out the *Limits to visited link styles* on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)

Try updating the `.navBar-Container ul>li a:link` with a background color so that the `:visited` can overwrite this. This worked for me:

```
.navBar-Container ul>li a:link {
  color: navy;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:white;
}
```

Here a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/andresabadia/gna7yjtf/2/

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If `a:link` doesn't have a background colour defined, then `:visited` will override whatever other style it has (even if that style comes from the browser's default stylesheet)

Comment: @Quentin Check out the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Comment: @Quentin I updated my answer. I hope the explanation is more clear now.

Comment: @Quentin the docs a very clear about this. I'm quoting them in the first paragraph. Are you implying that the docs are wrong?

Comment: @AndresAbadia Thank you very much. Then, please, how can I change the color and background-color of the **current navigation link**?

Comment: @BrightJovanny just change the current properties on the `.navBar-Container ul>li a:link` selector.